# Can't change default Java on Mac (Mojave 10.14.6)

Tags: java, jenkins

Bigger picture: I am trying to get a local version of Jenkins running and per their documentation I need Docker (done) and Java (also done). When I go to run Jenkins I receive a warning that the app requires Java 8.0 or 11.0 and I am running 12.0. I go to Oracle site, download 8.0 version and install. Run Jenkins again, same error.

In Terminal I run:

`java -version`

which returns:

`openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16`

I then check to see what versions of Java I have installed.

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

which returns

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    12.0.1, x86_64: "OpenJDK 12.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_221, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I then run:

`export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8'`

and

`java -version`

which returns

`openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16`

why did the default Java not switch to Java SE 8?

I can work somewhat with the command line but it is not really my area of competency, so be patient. : ) Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, posting here for others:

I added

`export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8'`

to my bash_profile file then ran

`source bash_profile`

then checking Java version showed the correct one. Only do this if you want to permanently change the default Java.